# Grading limitless variables

Tags: average, percentages

I am trying to calculate the quality of a triangle. Parameters are skewness, aspect ratio, and size. Skewness ranges between 0 and 1. Aspect ratio is the ratio of longest edge to shortest edge. Likewise size is the ratio of area of triangle to that of certain ideal triangle. I would like to get a score over 100 such as:

```
score = skewness*coefSkew
      + ar*coefAR
      + size*coefSize
```

where, coefficients are set as (20,60,20). The problem is with aspect ratio and size since they have no upper limits so I can't grade them over something whereas skewness can be graded over 1. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of functions that map $(0,+\infty)$ to a finite interval.  For example, $\tan^{-1} x$ maps $(0,+\infty)$ to $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: Do you know a reference about a list of those functions?

Comment: @shibli Considering there are uncountably many of these function a reference is unlikely. Even if you require continuity you still get uncountably many functions. Even restricting yourself to functions with a closed form parametrized by reals you get uncountably many. What you probably want to do is come up with some conditions you wish to impose on the function and ask a more directed question. Just to point out you don't even need trig functions consider $\frac{1}{x+1}$ maps $(0,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$.